# postgres how to get data from multiple databases

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc

i have 2 PostgreSQL databases on different port: DB1 on port 5432 and DB2 on port 5431

and i have code to get data from DB1 like this :

```
try {
    Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
    String conString = "jdbc:postgresql://127.0.0.1:5432/DB1?user=MyUser&pass=MyPass" ; 
    c = DriverManager.getConnection(conString);
      st = c.createStatement();
      ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(query);
      while (rs.next()){
          vaArrL.add(rs.getDouble("va"));
          vbArrL.add(rs.getDouble("vb"));
          vcArrL.add(rs.getDouble("vc"));
      }
```

and work good when i send singe query to DB1 only. 
 but now, i have query to both databases together like :

```
select va, vb from  DB1.public.t1 where datatime >=  1417384860 and datatime <=  1417381199 
union  
select va, vb from dblink('hostaddr=127.0.0.1 port=5431 dbname=DB2 user=MyUser password =MyPass '::text,
           'select va, vb 
            from Db2.public.t2 order by datatime ')
            datos(va integer,vb integer);
```

when i run query from pgAdmin i get result

but when i sent query to gunction i get : connection  not available

Now. How can i send my query to function and i get values?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try using JDBC's [`setCatalog`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html#setCatalog-java.lang.String-) method?

`setCatalog's` javadoc states that:

> Calling setCatalog has no effect on previously created or prepared
>   Statement objects. It is implementation defined whether a DBMS prepare
>   operation takes place immediately when the Connection method
>   prepareStatement or prepareCall is invoked. For maximum portability,
>   setCatalog should be called before a Statement is created or prepared.

```
try {
    Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
    // Connect to DB1 (specified in connection string/URL).
    String conString = "jdbc:postgresql://127.0.0.1:5432/DB1?user=MyUser&pass=MyPass" ; 
    c = DriverManager.getConnection(conString);
    st = c.createStatement();

    // Execute query on DB1.
    ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(query);
    while (rs.next()){
        vaArrL.add(rs.getDouble("va"));
        vbArrL.add(rs.getDouble("vb"));
        vcArrL.add(rs.getDouble("vc"));
    }

    // Switch to DB2 and execute query.
    c.setCatalog("DB2");    
    Statement st2 = c.createStatement();
    ResultSet rs2 = st2.executeQuery(...);
}
```

If the JDBC driver doesn't support `setCatalog`, then you can execute the SQL query `USE DB2` explicitly but this might affect already open statements (I'm not sure about this).

---

Edit: OP wants all results from both databases in the same ResultSet.

Assuming that DB1 and DB2 are on same server, I'd recommend creating a view in database DB1 which can access tables in database DB2 and return combined results. Then you can just `SELECT *` from the view via JDBC and get the results.

You can use a query like this for your view (assuming that the view is created in DB1):

```
SELECT all.va, all.vb FROM
    (SELECT va, vb, datatime FROM t2
     UNION
    SELECT va, vb, datatime FROM DB2.public.t2) all
ORDER BY all.datatime
```

Note: To access a table in another database, you need to specify [db-name].[schema].[tablename].

If your query needs dynamic arguments, then you can create a stored procedure instead of a view.

Comment: no i want all data in one ResultSet because i need to grantee no duplicate in data. thank you for try help me

Comment: @Kingimbrator Please mark my answer as correct if it works for you.

Comment: ok but i don't know what u mean from all , and what your mean about view ?

Comment: DB1 and DB2 in same server but each on run on different port

Comment: By server, i meant database server in my answer. Looking at your question now and based on your comment, it is clear that both db1 and db2 are on separate database servers  (since they're running on different ports). In that case, none of the solutions mentioned in my answer will work since they were based on the assumption that db1 and db2 are in the same database server. You will have to create 2 different JDBC connections in your Java code, execute the query on both of them and then merge data from their ResultSets in Java. You can abstract this into a separate Java class though.

Comment: ok ,How can i make one JDBC connection for 2 port on DB? How can i merge data in one ResultSets  after separate connections ?

Answer (score 0):

i am find 1 solution 
i am use 2 connection and send to query from client to xmlrpc server, here :

```
String conString = "jdbc:postgresql://" + host + ":" + port + "/" + DBName + 
            "?user=" + user + "&pass=" + pass;

String conString1 = "jdbc:postgresql://" + host + ":" + port2 + "/" + DBName2 + 
            "?user=" + user + "&pass=" + pass;

       c = DriverManager.getConnection(conString);
      c2 = DriverManager.getConnection(conString1);

      st = c.createStatement();
      st2 = c2.createStatement();       
          List<ResultSet> resultSets = new ArrayList<>();
          resultSets.add(st.executeQuery(query));
          resultSets.add(st2.executeQuery(query2));
           ResultSets rs = new ResultSets(resultSets);
      while (rs.next()){
          unbArrL.add(rs.getUnbalance("unbalance"));
      }
```

and resultSets class to get values from DB is :

```
class ResultSets {

 private java.util.List<java.sql.ResultSet> resultSets;

    private java.sql.ResultSet current;


    public ResultSets(java.util.List<java.sql.ResultSet> resultSets) {
        this.resultSets = new java.util.ArrayList<>(resultSets);
        current = resultSets.remove(0);
    }

    public boolean next() throws SQLException {
        if (current.next()) {
            return true;
        }else if (!resultSets.isEmpty()) {
            current = resultSets.remove(0);
            return next();
        }
        return false;
    }
    public Double getUnbalance(String unbalance) throws SQLException{
        return current.getDouble("unbalance");
    }
```

}